# How to combine with getattr() dynamically loadet python modules with lambda: in python?

Tags: python, nuke

From the environment (it is a graphic program called nuke) is given a global object where I can add menu items and connect it with a function. this global object works like this:

```
menu.addCommand("Do This!", lambda: DoThings())
```

I would like to read dynamically python modules and add the module functions as an item in the global menu object. I wrote a class to do that. A simplified version of my class:

```
class mymenu():
.
.
.
def _builMenuFromPath(self, basepath, module):

    items = []

    # ...
    # there is code to build the items list. this is a list of the python filenames
    # ...

    if len(items) > 0:

        for item in items:

            try:
                f = getattr(__import__(module + "." + item), item) # item is the python filename of an module in the folder with the python files and module is the folder

                menu.addCommand(item, lambda: f.call()) # f.call() is a function in the dynamic loaded python file

            except Exception, e:
                pass
```

The dynamic import works very well. But every generated menuitem is linked to the last imported function. So that every menuitems do the same.

I'm not a professional programmer. So I think I do a simple mistake.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing f.call instead of lambda:f.call().

Comment: @Jonas Take a look at the explanation for this provided in my answer.

Comment: @Jonas Anytime. Please make sure to mark the answer that has answered your question as "answered" (the checkmark right next to it). This will mark your question as answered.

Comment: @Jonas The usual term for clicking on the tick is to "accept" the answer, or mark it "accepted". The function is both to indicate that the question is resolved, and to designate one answer as the most useful.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. I am also quite a new member to to this website, so I wasn't aware of the correct terminology.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that in the expression `lambda: f.call()`, `f` is a free term which refers to the variable `f` in the enclosing scope. This means that changes in the value of `f` are apparent inside the lambda. For example:

```
>>> n = 1
>>> lambda: n
<function <lambda> at 0x00000000027F0898>
>>> l = lambda: n
>>> l()
1
>>> n = 2
>>> l()
2
```

However, the `lambda` is unnecessary because functions and methods in python are objects, which can themselves be passed wherever any callable (like a lambda) can be passed. In this code:

```
menu.addCommand(item, f.call)
```

`f.call` is an expression which will evaluate to a bound method which is callable.

Comment: Thank you. I think now i understand how exactly lambda works. In my way it couldn't be worked.

Comment: @Jonas No problem. It's something a lot of people need time to get to grips with. Go ahead and vote and accept.